# Using REGEXP_SUBSTR to get a specific text in a string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a string wherein lots of data is being stored. The string looks like this:

```
DUTBOARD|A1DT25522;LOADBOARD|A2LB1896;PROBECARD|A4PC40257;PROGRAMNAME|DS2781;TESTOPTION|POSTBAKE;TESTTEMP|ROOM TEMP
```

What I need is to display only the Dutboard, Loadboard, Probecard, Cable and Motherboard and their values. I was planning to use REGEXP_SUBSTR and then concatenate them all. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  'DUTBOARD|A1DT25522;LOADBOARD|A2LB1896;PROBECARD|A4PC40257;PROGRAMNAME|DS2781;TESTOPTION|POSTBAKE;TESTTEMP|ROOM TEMP' hw
  , regexp_substr('DUTBOARD|A1DT25522;LOADBOARD|A2LB1896;PROBECARD|A4PC40257;PROGRAMNAME|DS2781;TESTOPTION|POSTBAKE;TESTTEMP|ROOM TEMP', '(;|^)LOADBOARD\|(.*)(;|$)', 1, 1, '', 2) lol
FROM dual
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: ... and?  Does it produce the result you want?

Comment: Hello PM 77-1, Not really. I was just trying to get the Dutboard first. But the query returns all the text past the DUTBOARD|. Thanks

Comment: `'(;|^)LOADBOARD\|(.*?)(;|$)'`

Comment: Hello Agor this is wonderful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tab AS
     (SELECT     REGEXP_SUBSTR
                    ('DUTBOARD|A1DT25522;LOADBOARD|A2LB1896;PROBECARD|A4PC40257;PROGRAMNAME|DS2781;TESTOPTION|POSTBAKE;TESTTEMP|ROOM TEMP',
                     '[^;]+',
                     1,
                     LEVEL
                    ) regular_expression
            FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR
                    ('DUTBOARD|A1DT25522;LOADBOARD|A2LB1896;PROBECARD|A4PC40257;PROGRAMNAME|DS2781;TESTOPTION|POSTBAKE;TESTTEMP|ROOM TEMP',
                     '[^;]+',
                     1,
                     LEVEL
                    ) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (regular_expression, '[^|]+'),
       REGEXP_REPLACE (regular_expression, '.*\|([^ ]*).*', '\1')
  FROM tab
```

**Output**

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17310

Comment: Hello Gaurav, I appreciate your answer. But I need the output to be like this: DUTBOARD|A1DT25522;LOADBOARD|A2LB1896;PROBECARD|A4PC40257;

Comment: @GianIsTheName:Sorry I am not able to understand your input as well as output , the output you mentioned in the comment above is same as input, Can you please elaborate your Question?

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking to extract those specific fields and then re-concatenate the data?  Would this work for you if you're not particularly attached to REGEX_SUBSTR?

```
WITH TestStringsCTE AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '.*DUTBOARD\|([^;|]+);.*', '\1') AS DUTBOARD
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '.*LOADBOARD\|([^;|]+);.*', '\1') AS LOADBOARD
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '.*PROBECARD\|([^;|]+);.*', '\1') AS PROBECARD
  FROM TestStrings)

SELECT ('DUTBOARD'||'|'||DUTBOARD||';'
        ||'LOADBOARD'||'|'||LOADBOARD||';'
        ||'PROBECARD'||'|'||PROBECARD||';') AS str FROM TestStringsCTE;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19ee7/15